# retrieving non-visible nodes in Zoomcharts

Tags: zoomcharts

I a looking for a way to access non-visible nodes in a Zoomcharts NetChart .

```
chart.nodes()
```

returns only visible nodes, while

```
exportData(false,true)
```

allows me to export a list including hidden nodes in json.

Is there a function available to retrieve nodes, including hidden ones? I need this in a case of dynamic loading, so I can set the hidden status (I assume this is the data.loaded key) to false in case a hidden node is also in the result set that is returned from the server.

usecase:

I'm browsing a graph, and by setting nodefilters certain nodes will be hidden. When I load additional nodes dynamically, I want to force these nodes to be visible depending on the result of my query which may contain nodes and relations to nodes that are hidden.

If I can't set the properties of a hidden nodes, I can't set them to a value that makes them reappear because the match nodefilter.

Hope this is clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no function to access individual hidden nodes.

Can you expand you use case a bit more? What exactly do you want to process in hidden nodes?
In most dynamic loading cases a simple addData call should work.

Comment: case extended in original question